# How to resize icon to 48x48 from 1001 × 1506 in gimp?

Tags: icons, image-scaling, gimp

apologize for this really basic question, but I can't find a correct way in resizing icons. I want to resize this image with 1001x1506 px (300 dpi) to 48x48 px (160 dpi) for my icon in android app. I'm using gimp as my editor and I'm not used to this photo editor(adobe is not an option).

I've tried to scale it from original-500-200-48 but the image is already pixelated and I really dont know how to prevent it from pixelating while reducing size.

I would really appreciate your inputs.

thank you.

**UPDATE ANSWER:**

After searching for awhile, I found this good tutorial. And I was able to resize my images from large size(ex. 1024x1002) down to different icon size(ex. 48x48,72x72). http://gimp-tutorials.net/How-to-make-an-icon-from-a-picture

And also this link also helped me the different sizes and dimensions for android icons. http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

Hope it will also help you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for tutorials, if found this good tutorial. And I was able to resize my images from large size(ex. 1024x1002) down to different icon size(ex. 48x48,72x72). http://gimp-tutorials.net/How-to-make-an-icon-from-a-picture

And also this link also helped me the different sizes and dimensions for android icons.
http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

Hope it will also help you guys.

Answer (score 0):

In the menu, go to Image > Scale image... and try playing with the interpolation setting.

Comment: hi FireLeopard, I already tried those steps but the result of my image in 48x48 is so pexilated. any other tips? thanks